# Установка windows службы

Tags: c#, windows-service

В командной строке работает:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>InstallUtil.exe "C:\WindowsService1.exe"
```

Но я хочу произвести установку через свое приложение:

```
        System.Diagnostics.Process prc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();            
        prc.StartInfo.FileName = @"С:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe ""C:\WindowsService1.exe""";
        prc.Start();
```

Выдает ошибку не удается найти указанный файл, хотя путь верный (в локальной переменной он аналогичен CMD). В чем дело?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как насчет воспользоваться [`ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.managedinstallerclass.installhelper(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Пример:

```
public bool InstallService(string servicePath)
{
    try
    {
        ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new[] { servicePath });

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Учтите, что `ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper()` может быть долгим процессом, поэтому я бы советовал предварительно обернуть его в таску и сделать этот метод ассинхронным.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/660534/c-автоматическая-установка-windows-службы

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать немного изменить вызов метода Start. Сейчас вы передаёте запускаемое приложение вместе с аргументами. Попробуйте использовать другую перегрузку метода Start.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx

Т.е. в вашем примере это будет что-то вроде этого:

```
Process.Start("С:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe", "C:\WindowsService1.exe");
```

Или же так:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("С:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe");

startInfo.Arguments = "C:\WindowsService1.exe";

Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Ещё, как вариант, можно воспользоваться библиотекой Topshelf http://topshelf-project.com/, которая сильно упрощает работу с Windows Service.

После компиляции проект установка сервиса будет выглядеть как:

```
MyService.exe install
```

Answer (score -1):

Как вариант.Есть такой набор инструментов называется `WIX`,для создания установщиков.http://www.schiffhauer.com/wix-template-for-installing-a-windows-service/ стоит взглянуть,преимущества его использования заключаются в следующем.В нём можно указывать,зависимости для службы,возможность переустанавливать,обновлять или удалять её,через установку и удаления программ.Вместо использования `InstallUtil` или `sc` инструментов.

Comment: Вы предлагаете сделать инсталлер и потом его программно запускать из приложения?