# Автоматическая установка Windows службы

Tags: c#, windows-service

Использую такой код:

```
public bool InstallService(string servicePath)
{
    try
    {
        ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new[] { servicePath });

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Но во время установки выскакивает окно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А как ее автоматически установить, например, с системной учетной записью?

Comment: Можете приложить скрин этого окна?

Comment: добавил скриншот

Comment: Странно, у меня такого нет на чистом проекте. Покажите может код инсталлера сервиса...

Comment: Да все в порядке спасибо, это просто визуал студио заглючило

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В метод `ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper` перадавайте параметры, так же как, если бы Вы просто использовали `InstallUtil.exe`:

```
public bool InstallService(string servicePath)
{
    try
    {
        ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new string[] { "/i", "/username=yourUserName", 
                              "/password=yourPassword", servicePath });

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: дополнение к ответу: под системной учетной записью (LocalSystem) установить не получится, если только сервис по-умолчанию под ней не ставится (в исходниках сервиса должно быть указано processInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem). Но можете установить под пользователем, которым логинитесь, не обязательно же системного.